# Access arraylist from another method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, arraylist, arguments, command-line-arguments

Hi I am a beginner of C#, please help me with the following code:

Basically I am trying to take the first argument as a file name to open a file and store the words into an ArrayList array, (this class I have wrote in another Class and it works fine), and the second argument will be taken and use for comparing the length with the strings in the arraylist, whenever a string length matches the input string, it will be stored in a new arraylist wordLength, and print to screen.

When I wrote the comparing method within the Main method, it works fine, but I need to access the arrayList wordLength, therefore I wrote a separated method to get wordLength array as return.

If anyone could help me understand the reason why the code doesn't work, that will be much much appreciated, and please bare my poor explanation, since it is only the second week I am learning C#, there are a lot of knowledge going through my mind and I am getting confused with some details all the time. Thanks in advanced!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{          
    ArrayList array = DataFileReader.DataFile(args[0]);
    String characters = args[0];
}

public static ArrayList WordLength(String characters, ArrayList array)
{

    ArrayList wordLength = new ArrayList();
    foreach (string line in array)
    {
        if (line.Length == characters.Length)
        {
            wordLength.Add(line);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    return wordLength;
}
```

Comment: Side note - don't use `ArrayList`. Use generic `List<T>` instead

Comment: You should call `WordLength` at the end of the `Main`: `WordLength(characters, array)` and then use returned `wordLength`

Comment: Its unclear what you are trying to do, are you trying to assign the return value of `WordLength` to something else? (you do something like this in your first line of code if so)

Comment: [comparision between arrraylist and list<T>](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Difference-between-ArrayList-and-Generic-List-in-C-Net-and-VBNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace Crossword
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                ArrayList array = DataFileReader.DataFile(args[0]);
                String characters = args[0];
                ArrayList wordLength = WordLength(characters,array); // this will pass the variables to your method
        }
        public static ArrayList WordLength(String characters, ArrayList array)
        {

            ArrayList wordLength = new ArrayList();
            foreach (string line in array)
                if (line.Length == characters.Length){
                    wordLength.Add(line);
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
          }

            return wordLength;
        }
}
```

**P.S: Just try what Sergey Berezovskiy said  "Side note - don't use ArrayList. Use generic List instead"**

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out one minute ago and saw this comment! But still thank you kindly!